# Setting up Raspberry Pi 3 using Mac Laptop

Tags: raspbian

I bought a Raspberry Pi Starter Kit with NOOBS already installed on the Micro SD Card. Now I have my microUSD plugged into the Pi and the HDMI connected from Pi to Mac, which doesn't do anything since HDMI on Mac is only outbound. How do I now install Raspbian on the PI and then afterwards control the Pi from my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a TV or computer monitor (NOT Mac) to connect to that has HDMI, plug your RPi HDMI into it. ***YOU CANNOT USE NOOBS WITHOUT A MONITOR.***

As an alternative, you can [download Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and install it directly to your SD card with your Mac--the only way to set up with no monitor for the Pi.

After you have completed this, simply run `ssh pi@<your_pi's_ip_address>` or `ssh pi@raspberrypi` in your Mac's terminal, enter the password for your Pi (the default is `raspberry`), and you're good to go! :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a monitor for your rpi first boot is a way to resolve your current problem. Then, you can use the remote login to control your computer.